# Is it possible to write a webpage that supports javascript or php scripting on the server?

Tags: javascript, post, server-side, execution, keyvaluepair

I have a pair of web-pages that in the first page, collects and posts a number of values, and a php page that receives these values, creates a formatted html page and send it back to the browser.

Here is a form-demo page on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/eYYyKyo).  As of yet I don't have a public server to post to, so there isn't a demonstration side for the server-side of the form-demo page.

Here is my server-side php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Username-Password Test.php</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      $_POST Keys:&nbsp;
<?php
echo implode( ', ', array_keys( $_POST ) );
?>
    <br />
    <table>
<?php
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
?>
      <tr>
        <td style="background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(1,1,1,1) 1px, transparent 2px) repeat-x; background-size: 10px 23px;">
          <span style="background-color: white; padding-right: 5px;">
<?php
        echo $key . PHP_EOL;
?>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
<?php
        echo '&nbsp;' . $value . PHP_EOL;
?>
        </td>
      </tr>

<?php
    } // End of foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) ...
?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This page works fine on a server that supports php scripting, but when I try to run it on my local computer, which doesn't have a web-server installed and I don't want to install, it simply sends the whole page as text to my browser.

Is possible in the php page, which runs on the server, to detect if php script contained in that page is supported, and if so, run it, but if not, run a javascript also in the same page that can receive the values and put them in a similar report that is sent back to the browser?  If this is possible, please provide links to examples.  If possible, I would like the solution to run locally without needing to run a web-server locally, when a remote server isn't possible, similar to the way javascript is permitted by the browser.

If this isn't possible, then how can I use regular javascript that is also in the second page that is sent back to the browser to receive the posted values and put them in the report produced by that page?

Thank you

Comment: For PHP, you need to install a server. There's no way around that. Don't try to execute the PHP remotely - much too complicated.

Comment: You want to run a PHP page on your local computer, without installing a server - but then in the next paragraph you say "the php page, which runs on the server". Which server? You haven't installed one.

Comment: Yes, you could trivially create a JavaScript that outputs this table, running locally inside the browser. But I'd recommend to do it in a single, interactive web page then, not two pages where one tries to send values to the other.

Comment: Thank you Bergi and Kaya3.  This question just out of curiosity.  My initial hope was to be able to run the two pages from either a server with PHP or from my local system with another script language, such as javascript when I'm not connected to the internet and so unable to get to the server with PHP.  I don't want to install a web-server on my personal computer.  Since asking this question I realize the best way without a server is to just go with the javascript to hide the <?php ... ?> blocks and process the report, but I still need to know how to echo back the values in the post.

Comment: I was able to post or get the second web-page from a remote server, but not from my local computer, using a  XMLHttpRequest send call.  The call to fetch the second local file complained about the file protocol no being supported for post/get methods.  My goal for the local file was load and execute the embedded javascript  if it still contained embedded unexecuted php script.  So unless this can somehow  be done without running a web-service on my local computer, I'm just work with remote servers when available.